# Why Can't I Execute RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

Working through Michael Hartle's tutorial and I cannot execute RSpec; terminal is presenting with the following error:

```
/Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/Tutorials/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec-helper (LoadError)
    from /Users/coreymkimball/Canvi/Tutorials/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/coreymkimball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

It states that there has been a load error in the particular file; not sure how to go about creating a new one, or getting over this troubleshooting hurdle. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely find that the file you made in your spec directory is called `spec_helper`, not `spec-helper`. Change the require at the top of your `static_pages_spec.rb` to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, that's great, very simple; can't believe I let it slip by me- thank you, appreciate it!